# How to upload default static file to the ImgeField?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to upload my default static image if no image input is provided but it is not working. It is just adding the path but actual static image is not uploading.

```
  from django.templatetags.static import static

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.image:
            self.image = static('images/default-img.png')
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: why don't you set ```ImageFiled(defautl='images/default-img.png')```

Answer (score 0):

```
pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='blah', default='path/to/my/default/image.jpg')
```

Actually this does work. Although perhaps not ideally.

Comment: Please do not add normal text into code blocks. Also: Why post two answers to the same question?

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand your question clearly..
but here is my suggestion..

```
 from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
 f = open("filename_location", "rb")
 file_obj = ContentFile(f)
 self.image = file_obj
```

here is the link for more about content file https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/files/file/

Answer (score 0):

***Might be TLDR***

As far as I knew, `static` dir. purpose is to serve files from Django. Such as `collectstatic` from `manage.py`

When you run this, `./manage.py collectstatic` on your shell, mean your static modules files will be store to your `static` directory.

When your **DEBUG** in `settings.py` is **False**, Django no longer serve those files.
That's why you need to collectstatic first.

In production, Django also recommend to set **DEBUG** to **False** on production, because when you set this to **True** while deployment on server/hosting, user from frontend may know what happen with your backend, just like when you develope your application.

[For more information about static files in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/)

---

If you want to upload a file/s, most of the case it's not recommended to stored file/s to `static` dir.

Used `media` instead.

[Information to serving files uploaded by a user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)

---

To solve that, you can use/set `static` and `media` in your `settings.py`

###### *assuming that your project root directory were like this:*

```py
/base_dir                      #0
|
|
|__ /backend
|  |
|  |
|  |__ /myapp                   #3
|  |  |
|  |  |__ /migrations
|  |  |__ __init__.py
|  |  |__ admin.py
|  |  |__ apps.py
|  |  |__ models.py
|  |  |__ tests.py
|  |  |__ urls.py
|  |
|  |
|  |__ /configuration           #2
|  |  |
|  |  |__ __init__.py
|  |  |__ asgi.py
|  |  |__ settings.py
|  |  |__ urls.py
|  |  |__ wsgi.py
|  |
|  |
|  |__ /media
|  |  |
|  |  |__ default-avatar.png
|  |
|  |
|  |__ /static
|  |  |
|  |  |__ /css
|  |  |__ /js
|  |
|  |
|  |__ manage.py
|
|
|__ /virtualenv                 #1
```

###### explanation #{number}

- **#0**

  - your workspace directory
- **#1**

  - came from:

    ```sh
    virtualenv virtualenv
    ```

    about [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)
- **#2**

  - came from:

    ```sh
    django-admin startproject configuration backend
    ```
- **#3**

  - came from:

    ```sh
    ./manage.py startapp myapp
    ```

---

Okay, now go to your `settings.py` and locate where:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

is exists.

Then edit it to:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
if DEBUG:
    # Mean: during DEBUG == True, or under your development, 
    # it will use this config directories for static and media
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        (BASE_DIR / 'static/')
    ]
    MEDIA_ROOT = (BASE_DIR / 'media/')
else:
    # Mean: DEBUG == False, use _ROOT where you also need to collectstatic first
    STATIC_ROOT = (BASE_DIR / 'static/')
    MEDIA_ROOT = (BASE_DIR / 'media/')
```

By default, your **DEBUG** is **False**

set to **True** then go to your shell/bash, go to where `manage.py` exists and type:

```sh
./manage.py collectstatic
```

*also activate your virtualenv, before use that command*.

Now you *may* see admin static files under **admin** directory on your `static` dir.

---

Next, go to your `urls.py` under `/configuration` dir. and edit/add:

```py
# assuming this will be a common case for admin url and one application
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [

    # your admin url path
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),


    # your app/s url/s will be here
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),

]


# increment `static` dir to urlpatterns
urlpatterns += static(
    settings.STATIC_URL,
    document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT
)
# increment `media` dir to urlpatterns
urlpatterns += static(
    settings.MEDIA_URL,
    document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
)
```

When your application start/restarted, those increment will always be accessible to urlpatterns.

For monolith app without subdomain, this is safe.

---

Time to configure your `models.py` under your app dir.

*in this case, your app name is `myapp`*.

`/myapp/models.py`

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# anyway, let's say this model is for user account information
class UserAccount(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True, blank=True
    )

    # this one is your case
    avatar = models.ImageField(
        default='default-avatar.png' # look what inside `./base_dir/backend/media/`
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        null=True, blank=True
    )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        null=True, blank=True
    )
```

Don't forget to do `makemigrations` and/or `migrate`, then register that models to `admin.py` under your app directory.

`/myapp/admin.py`

```py
from django.contrib import admin


# import your models
from .models import UserAccount


# register your user account
admin.site.register(UserAccount)
```

Now you may `runserver` and test it.

---

The things is, admin/superuser is also counted as user.

So, whenever you want to upload some file to your server now/later

`or`

with frontend logic by yourself or active users,

all uploaded file/s will be store to `media` directory that you already configured.

Watch your server log.

Hope this will give you a bit more understanding about serving files in Django application.

Comment: Try to play around on your admin frontend interface at `127.0.0.1:8000/admin/`

or used POST method logic.

Mostly uploaded file will store to `media` directory